# Eclipse Gradle dependencies are not updated in Web App Libraries

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have a Gradle project (imported and generated using Eclipse's Gradle plugin) in Spring Tool Suite edition of Eclipse (3.2.0). It works most of the time, but sometimes, dependencies are getting out-of-sync between "Gradle Dependencies" and "Web App Libraries" in the project. Here is what I mean:

I define a compile dependency as following:

```
compile(group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'myClient', version: '0.2.1')
```

Then, after I do "Gradle -> Refresh All" I see that the dependency lib "myClient-0.2.1.jar" is in the list of the "Gradle Dependencies", and in the list under the "web App Libraries".

Now, after some time, I decide to use a newer version of this lib:

```
compile(group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'myClient', version: '0.2.2')
```

I again do "Gradle -> Refresh All", I also tried to refresh the project, re-build it, open/close the project and Eclipse, but what I see is:

The dependency under the "Gradle Dependencies" is indeed updated and is listed as "myClient-0.2.2.jar". But, the dependency under the "Web App Libraries" refuses to be updated and stays as "myClient-0.2.1.jar". this, obviously, wracks havoc to my app as now my code is not referencing correct newer classes and shows up all red in Eclipse.

One workaround that works *sometimes* is to nuke the whole project, and re-build it from scratch, but this is rather more radical than what I'd like to do :) And it does not work sometimes. It looks like I cannot explicitly control what goes into the "Web App Libraries" - so even though I see that a wrong lib is listed in the Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Web App Libraries  - I cannot change it there.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated,
Thanks!
Marina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Try a gradle cleanEclipseWtp eclipseWtp, this worked for me.
The WebApp libs will be up to date.

Best regards

Max

Comment: I have also found one more way to do this - you need to physically clean out gradle cache on your local file system - you can see the location of the cache when examining Gradle Dependencies - it shows the full path. So, if I physically remove all cache, and re-fresh the Gradle dependencies - they get in sync with Web App libs too.

Comment: `Gradle > Refresh All` should do that (did for me and thanks Max, this fixed my problem).  Perhaps the behaviour of Refresh All has changed since this question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

1)delete it without deleting contents on disk
2)Import ... Existing projects into workspace and import the gradle-example project back
3)the Gradle Dependencies container is named nicely
4)restart Eclipse
5)the Gradle Dependencies container of the gradle-example project has the weird name I'm reporting